# How do I cast to longint unsigned in systemverilog?

Tags: system-verilog, verilator

I want to cast logic packed array into `longint unsigned` in systemverilog and then I can export it using DPI-C to C++ unsigned long. The simulator I am using is Verilator. Check the example below.

```
logic[31:0] v1;
logic[63:0] v2;

int a = signed'(v1); //cast to signed int
int b = int'(v1); //cast to signed int
int unsigned c = unsigned'(v1); //cast to unsigned int
longint d = longint'(v2); //cast to signed long
//longint unsigned e = longint unsigned'(v2); //This doesn't work. I need to cast to unsigned long.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a SystemVerilog type without a space in it using `typedef`. Here's an example:

```systemverilog
// ..
typedef longint unsigned uint64_t;
uint64_t e = uint64_t'(v2);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for any kind of cast unless sign extension is required. There is already implicit casting between 4-state and 2-state types.

You can just write:

```
longint d = v2;
```

Comment: I am not casting to change between 4-state and 2-state types.

Comment: @Topa, `logic` is a 4-state type. `int/longint` is a two state type. You can just write `longint d = v2;`

Comment: I know that but my question wasn't about casting between 2 state and 4 state datatypes. My question was about casting in general.

Comment: OK, but I am trying to tell you the problem you ran into in the first place (cast only allows a single name, needs a `typedef`) , could have been avoided because you didn't need the cast for the DPI.